# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined while init second map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I have to maps in my app. The first one appears after log in and works perfectly. The second one is placed in another component, while instantiation I receive an error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
```

The google map script is placed in `index.html` and in both cases I'm using the `ngOnInit` method to create the map.

What can be wrong if one map works and the second one no ... ?

```
//imports
var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-friend-latest-position',
  templateUrl: 'friend-latest-position.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['friend-latest-position.component.css']
})
export class FriendLatestPositionComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  private location: Location = new Location();
  private email: string;
  private hasLocation: boolean = false;


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.email = this.route.snapshot.params['email'];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.getSelectedUser();
  }


  getSelectedUser() {
    // fetching data
   this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    const loc = {lat: this.location.latitude, lng: this.location.longitude};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: loc
    });
}
```

Comment: you should add code of how you call it

Comment: In the standard way like on the google dev page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Well, you should instantiate a map in ngAfterViewInit because that's when the component elements are added and available in the document

Comment: Nothing changed with `ngAfterViewInit `

Comment: How do you import the google maps library in your to file? And seriously, it's a lot easier to help if you post actual code

Comment: Snippet added. In the html I have only a div with id="map".

Comment: Looks like google maps script is not done loading. AFAIR you need to listen for the `load` event of the script if you load it async. How does the script tag look like? What about using https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps instead?

Comment: So why the first component with map inside works everytime ?

Comment: You should remove the var google; on top

Comment: Then I will have an error that google isn't recognizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
declare const google: any;
```

Or install the Google maps typings

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save-dev
```

If you use `var` your current Google object gets overwritten inside the scope of the typescript file.